# What is the proper syntax for creating a bash alias that git clones, cds, and opens that repo in a text editor (atom .) all in one?

Tags: bash

How do I tack bash commands on one after another and dynamically pass a variable, in this case a repo name, to the next bash command? I want to 'git clone ' && 'cd' into that directory && 'atom .' using an an alias in bash.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use an alias, and not a function or a script?

Comment: No reason, whatever works and can be easily called with a simple 'clone! <filename>' in the command line

Comment: An exclamation mark? That's actually a problem -- shell functions are only guaranteed to work with valid shell variable names. (Some shells are more lenient, but it's not guaranteed by the POSIX sh standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an alias for this job; a shell function is the right tool.

```
clone_and_open() {
  local dest=${2:-${1##*/}}        # if we were passed $2, use it; otherwise, trim $1
  git clone "$1" "$dest" || return # attempt a git clone, abort otherwise
  cd "$dest"             || return # cd into directory, or abort otherwise
  atom .                           # actually start your editor
}
```

...will let you run `clone_and_open https://github.com/example/example` to clone into a directory named `example` and open `atom` there, or `clone_and_open https://github.com/foobar/baz foobar-baz` to clone `baz` into a `foobar-baz` directory.

If you want to use a name that isn't valid for a shell function, then you might use an alias as well: `alias clone!='clone_and_open'`.

An alias only allows arguments to be appended at the end, so you can't put them at multiple separate places (as is needed here); consequently, *in and of itself*, one is inadequate to the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html):

```
function do-things {
    git clone $1 && cd $2 && echo $3 
}
```

If you're doing this sort of boilerplate setup often and for different projects, you may want to consider a tool like [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator), which allows you to create "profiles" for different projects and has hooks for scripting this sort of setup/teardown. (Full disclosure: I'm a contributor.)

Comment: Quoting is broken here, and the use of bashisms instead of POSIX-compliant syntax (in this particular instance where the extensions compromise portability but don't add any value) is unfortunate. (To be clear, the `function` keyword is a ksh-ism that bash supports for compatibility, but is *not* part of POSIX function declaration syntax).

Comment: (...to clarify "quoting is broken": If you pass a directory name with a space in either `$1` or `$2` position, instead of being treated as just one name it'll be split into two separate arguments; similarly, any `*` in a name, even if passed in quoted, will be replaced with a list of the local directory's contents).

Comment: ...and **please** don't link TLDP. Half of what we do in the freenode #bash channel is try to get people to unlearn bad practices they picked up from their documentation. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the `function` declaration syntax, and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar#shell_function_definitions for well-maintained docs on the compliant syntax.